# Why grep -vFf png.ll png.lll differs from grep -vFf png.lll png.ll?

Tags: linux, grep

```
$ cat png.ll
./packages/apps/Mms/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_smsmms.png
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi/messagebox_pressed_left.9.png
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi/messagebox_pressed_right.9.png
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi/messagebox_default_left.9.png
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi/messagebox_default_right.9.png
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi-finger/ic_contact_list_sim2.png
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi-finger/ic_contact_list_sim1.png

$ cat png.lll
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi-finger/ic_contact_list_sim2.png
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi-finger/ic_contact_list_sim1.png
```

The result of grep -Ff png.ll png.lll is same as result of grep -Ff png.lll png.ll

```
$ grep -Ff png.ll png.lll
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi-finger/ic_contact_list_sim2.png
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi-finger/ic_contact_list_sim1.png

$ grep -Ff png.lll png.ll
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi-finger/ic_contact_list_sim2.png
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi-finger/ic_contact_list_sim1.png
```

But the result of grep -vFf png.lll png.ll differs from the result of grep -vFf png.ll png.lll

```
$ grep -vFf png.lll png.ll
./packages/apps/Mms/res/mipmap-hdpi/ic_launcher_smsmms.png
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi/messagebox_pressed_left.9.png
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi/messagebox_pressed_right.9.png
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi/messagebox_default_left.9.png
./packages/apps/Mms/res/drawable-hdpi/messagebox_default_right.9.png

$ grep -vFf png.ll png.lll
```

Why? Why the last grep doesn't give any output?

Comment: by definition of options F and v for grep. grep -vFf png.ll png.lll will not return anything because there is no lines in png.lll, which are absent in  png.ll. Here  png.ll is a file with patterns to look for and   png.lll a file where the patterns have to be searched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running four different commands, and they are returning results as follows:

```
# Show me all lines in png.lll that are also in png.ll
grep -Ff png.ll png.lll

# Show me all lines in png.ll that are also in png.lll
grep -Ff png.lll png.ll

# Show me all lines in png.ll that are *not* in png.lll
grep -vFf png.lll png.ll

# Show me all lines in png.lll that are *not* in png.ll
grep -vFf png.ll png.lll
```

Hopefully this clears things up